# A tooltip-like dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Do you know of some jquery plugins that behaves like the tooltip dialog of the Flow App. ( screenshot here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/44597029.png/ ). I am currently making a web app that has a lot of tooltip dialog(if that's the right term..).

If there's no plugin, can somebody enlighten me on how to approach this thing?.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

qtip2 is one powerful tooltip jquery plugin

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Answer (score 0):

You are overloaded with choices in this case. Chose what suits you the best.

http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/